# Tensorflow object detection: Change input resolution of model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using Tensorflow's Object Detection API using the code provided in the [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to analyze high-resolution images (4K). I've tested a few pre-trained models provided in the [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). The models are configured to downscale the input image to a certain size specified in their [config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs). Due to resizing the input image by a large factor, small objects are left undetected in my images.

Is there a way to change the resolution the input images get resized to for the pre-trained models?

example: The `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco` pre-trained model has the following lines in its configuration file:

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
}
```

I tried changing the configuration file to resize to 600x600 and rerun `export_inference_graph.py` on the pre-trained model.ckpt to get a new inference graph. While this did export a new graph, the results were not as expected when using it for object detection. The results weren't accurate and when it did detect an object correctly the bounding box was too large by a factor of 2. So clearly this isn't the way to do it.

What I'm asking is: Whats the correct way of changing the input resolution for a pre-trained model?

Comment: HI @ignace-maes ! I see this was posted a while ago. I am in the exact same situation... have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Hey @Amir, I haven't been able to change the input resolution without retraining the model, no. I moved on to [YOLOv3](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) which allows changing the input resolution in a configuration file, without needing to retrain the model.